# Drupal 7 as an Oauth 2.0 provider

Tags: drupal-7, oauth-2.0

I am trying to make my Drupal 7 site an OAuth provider. I have found the Drupal modules for OAuth 1, yet I am having trouble with finding OAuth 2.0 provider modules.

I found this project at Drupalcode: http://drupalcode.org/project/oauth2.git it supports OAuth 2.0 for Drupal 6. While browsing to the repository, I saw the tags: "7.x-1.x-dev" and "7.x-1.x-Rj" (don't know what this Rj stands for..) which made me very happy. So I checked out the code and put that, together with the latest http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/ in my Drupal installation. However, when I wanted to enable the module in Drupal 7, it says: "This version is not compatible with Drupal 7.x and should be replaced."

Has anyone got any idea whether this module will work in Drupal 7? (the tags confuse me) If not, is there another module for OAuth 2.0 for Drupal?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This looks more appropriate for the drupal site >> http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be because the .info file don't have the version specified but has no harm using the module.

I think you should also try http://drupal.org/sandbox/sadashiv/1857254 for google_oauth2

Answer (score 2):

Here is OAuth 2 server for Drupal 7 https://drupal.org/project/oauth2_server

Answer (score 0):

spent some days for using Drupal7 as oauth2 provider and successfully implemented. I am sharing two github repositories

[I answered here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36602/drupal-7-as-an-oauth-2-0-and-or-1-0a-provider/144788#144788)